# Prove for a in $U_m$, $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ for some k>1

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Prove for $a$ in $U_m$, $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ for some $k>1$
This is basically equivalent to proving that if gcd(a,m)=1, then the function $m|a^k-1$ has an integer solution.
Can't use theorems related to orders directly, can't use Euler's totient theorem

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Take $k=\phi(m)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.  Are you familiar with Lagrange's theorem in group theory?

Comment: Did you mean $a^k$ where you typed $u^k$ in the title?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The set $\{ a^n \bmod m : n \in \mathbb N \}$ is finite.

Solution:

> $a^i \equiv a^j \bmod m$ for some $i>j$ and so $a^k \equiv 1 \bmod m$ for $k=i-j$.

Answer (score 0):

$U_m$ is a finite group with identity $1$; denote its order by $\phi(m)$.  Then, for $a$ in $U_m$, $a^{\phi(m)}=1$.